# Netbeans screen artifacting

Tags: java, netbeans, lines, artifact

I have noticed recently that in net beans sometimes lines are left on the screen and aren't cleaned up. I cant get a screen shot for some reason so an image from my phone will have to do:

[image: Here]

Is there a setting I need to change, or something? or is it a problem with my monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, just minimalize/resize window to redraw

Comment: Well, thats unfortunate.